# Need help resolving an Unhandled Exception Error

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've been learning to program for a few months now and I've been working on a program to manage student data. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class Student
{
private:
    string name;
    string course;
    int section;
    int grade;

public:
    void calcgrade();
    void getData();
    void showData();

};

void Student::calcgrade() 
{
    if (grade >= 90)

        grade = 'A';

    else if (grade >= 80)

        grade = 'B';

    else if (grade >= 70)

        grade = 'C';

    else if (grade >= 60)

        grade = 'D';

    else

        grade = 'F';
}

void Student::getData() 
{
    cout << "Enter the name of the student: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, name);

    cout << "Enter the course: ";
    cin >> course;

    cout << "Enter the section: ";
    cin >> section;

    cout << "Enter the grade received: ";
    cin >> grade;
    calcgrade();
}

void Student::showData()
{
    cout << ".......Student Information......" << endl;
    cout << "Student Name: " << name << endl;
    cout << "Course: " << course << endl;
    cout << "Section: " << section << endl;
    cout << "Grade: " << grade << endl;
    cout << endl;
}


void addData() 
{
    Student st; 
    ofstream fout; 
    fout.open("Student.data", ios::binary | ios::out | 
            ios::app); 
    st.getData(); 
    fout.write((char*)& st, sizeof(st)); 
    fout.close(); 
    cout << "Data Successfully Saved to File." << endl;
}

void displayData() 
{
    Student st;
    ifstream file;  
    file.open("Student.data", ios::in | ios::binary);

    if (file.is_open()) 
    {
        while (file.read((char*)& st, sizeof(st)))
        {
            st.showData(); 
        }

        cout << "Finished Reading Data From File." << 
                    endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
    }
    file.close();

}

void searchData()
{
    Student st;
    ifstream file;
    file.open("Student.data", ios::in | ios::binary);
    string search; 
    cout << "Please enter the first name of a student to search for: ";
    cin >> search;
    bool isFound = 0; 
    while (file.read((char*)& st, sizeof(st))) 
    {
        string temp = " ";
        getline(file, temp);
        for (int i = 0; i < search.size(); i++)
        {
            if (temp[i] == search[i])
                isFound = 1;
            else
            {
                isFound = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isFound) 
        {
            cout << "The name " << search << " was found in the database." << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (file.read((char*)& st, sizeof(st)) && (!isFound)) 
    {
        cout << "Name not found." << endl;
    }

    file.close();
}

void modifyData() 
{
    Student st;
    string stname;
    bool isFound = 0; 
    int pos;
    fstream file;

    file.open("Student.data", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);

    cout << "Enter the name of a student whose data you want to modify: ";
    cin >> stname;

    while (file.read((char*)& st, sizeof(st))) 
    {
        string temp = " ";
        getline(file, temp);
        for (int i = 0; i < stname.size(); i++)
        {
            if (temp[i] == stname[i])
                isFound = 1;
            else
            {
                isFound = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isFound)
        {
            pos = file.tellg(); 

            cout << "Current Data" << endl;
            st.showData();
            cout << "Modified Data" << endl;
            st.getData();
            file.seekg(pos - sizeof(st)); 
            file.write((char*)& st, sizeof(st));
        }

    }

    if (file.read((char*)& st, sizeof(st)) && (!isFound)) 
    {
        cout << "Name not found." << endl;
    }

    file.close();
}

void deleteData()
{
    Student st;
    string stname;
    bool isFound = 0;
    ifstream file;
    ofstream fout;

    file.open("Student.data", ios::in | ios::binary);
    fout.open("Temporary.data", ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);

    cout << "Enter the name of a student whose data you want to delete: ";
    cin >> stname;

    while (file.read((char*)& st, sizeof(st))) 
    {
        string temp = " ";
        getline(file, temp);
        for (int i = 0; i < stname.size(); i++)
        {
            if (temp[i] == stname[i])
                isFound = 1;
            else
            {
                isFound = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isFound)
        {

            cout << "Bleh" << endl;
            fout.write((char*)& st, sizeof(st));
        }
    }
    if (file.read((char*)& st, sizeof(st)) && (!isFound))
    {
        cout << "Name not found." << endl;
    }

    fout.close();
    file.close();

    remove("Student.data");
    rename("Temporary.data", "Student.data");
}
void printData()
{
    ifstream file;
    file.open("Student.data", ios::in | ios::binary);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        cout << file.rdbuf();
    }

    file.close();
}

int main()
{
    int num;


    do
    {
        cout << "...............STUDENT MANAGEMENT SYSTEM..............\n";
        cout <<  "======================================== ==============\n";
        cout << "0. Close Program. " << endl;
        cout << "1. Add Data. " << endl;
        cout << "2. List Data. " << endl;
        cout << "3. Modify Data. " << endl;
        cout << "4. Search For Data. " << endl;
        cout << "5. Print Data. " << endl;
        cout << "6. Delete Data. " << endl;

        cout << "Choose an option: ";
        cin >> num;

        if (num == 1)
        {
            addData();
        }
        else if (num == 2)
        {
            displayData();
        }
        else if (num == 3)
        {
            modifyData();
        }
        else if (num == 4)
        {
            searchData();
        }
        else if (num == 5)
        {
            printData();
        }
        else if (num == 6)
        {
            deleteData();
        }
    } while (num > 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Ideally, when the program runs, the user chooses an option, with different function calls depending on the number entered. The Add Data option works fine, but when choosing others, such as List Data or Search Data, I run into an error such as: Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation. _Pnext was 0x10A6A04.

Code in xmemory:

```
 inline void _Container_base12::_Orphan_all() noexcept {
    #if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
        if (_Myproxy != nullptr) { // proxy allocated, drain it
            _Lockit _Lock(_LOCK_DEBUG);

            for (_Iterator_base12** _Pnext = &_Myproxy->_Myfirstiter; *_Pnext != nullptr;
                *_Pnext = (*_Pnext)->_Mynextiter) {
                (*_Pnext)->_Myproxy = nullptr;
            }

            _Myproxy->_Myfirstiter = nullptr;
        }
```

Given there are no obvious errors in the code, I'd like a little help in figuring out what I've done wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.Have a look at the page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What was the last thing you changed in the code before the error appeared?

Comment: Thank you. The last bit of code I edited before trying out the program was the Student Management System formatting in main()

Comment: "Before trying out the program?" Do you mean that you wrote all of that code without testing any of it? Here's some advice they never seem to teach in CompSci courses: start with something small and simple that works perfectly, add complexity a little at a time, test at every step, and **never add to code that doesn't work.**

Comment: In `searchData()`, you read a `Student` from the file, but then you also call `getline`. On a *binary* file. What do you expect to get with that?

Comment: @nonavidprogrammer `while (file.read((char*)& st, sizeof(st)))` -- With this, the program is broken.  Your `Student` class contains members that are non-POD types, such as `std::string`.  You *cannot* read into types like this in binary mode.  I see this same "binary file" errors so many times, and wondering who is teaching to do this for C++ and objects like this.  Either get rid of the `std::string` members in your class and make them regular `char` arrays, or learn how to properly serialize objects.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. Now that I look at it again, the entire program is a mess. I've taken steps to fix things, being sure to test small segments this time, and things are going well. Most of the code in the program is from searching how to perform specific actions in C++ and trying to utilize features that I do not yet fully understand. Again, thank you for the assistance.

Comment: When you write:

if (grade >= 90)

        grade = 'A';

You store 65 to grade. Because of 'A' char it is 65. You have to use a different variable to store results like
"char gradescore;

if (grade >= 90)

        gradescore = 'A';"

Comment: @nonavidprogrammer -- Basically if `std::is_trivially_copyable<Student>()` returns `0`, then you can't read / write that type as binary.  That's how you can test for these things.